# hooks into the 'learndash_completion_redirect' to allow override of the redirect link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to redirect users to a survey form when they finish one of the three quizzes (defined by the $post_id) when clicking the continue button in the course that is of class 'learndash_completion_redirect'. This should only happen for these three quizzes (ids) but is currently being triggered on any instance of the continue button.

The continue button is defined as the above class, but I want to limit it to just 3 ids.

I have tried the code and the Learndash LMS is very limited as to custom definition of inputs

```
add_filter('learndash_completion_redirect', function($link, $post_id) {
if ( $post_id === 3126 || 3071 || 3003 ) {
$link = "https://www.rapquiz.vacd.org/post-course-survey/";
}
return $link;
},5,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I must admit that I don't fully understand your question, it seems like you're missing a bit of the logic for boolean `if`-expressions.
If you want to check whether `$post_id` is `3126 OR 3071 OR 3003`, you need to OR the result of the `===` comparison.
Therefore, you should change

```
if ( $post_id === 3126 || 3071 || 3003 ) {
```

to

```
if ( $post_id === 3126 || $post_id === 3071 || $post_id === 3003 ) {
```

Alternatively, especially if you want to extend the list later, you could use:

```
if ( in_array($post_id, [3126,3071,3003])) {
```

Which checks whether `$post_id` matches one of the array's elements (`3126,3071,3003`)

The reason for your old code accepting every value is that all numbers except `0` are treated as a boolean `TRUE`, therefore your expression so far matched

```
if ( $post_id === 3126 || TRUE || TRUE ) {
```

which eavluate

Comment: Well now it won't redirect at all. I will try to clarify. I want to redirect the user to the new $link only if they are on those 3 post_ids. This is LMS, so the quizzes are treated as posts. those quiz ids are the final quizzes of each course and the user should be redirected to a gravity form survey that is located on a standalone page.